# Autowiring working in one class but not in other

Tags: java, spring-mvc, autowired

I have an autowired class like this

```
@Component
public class APIPermissionCheck {
..............
}
```

its injecting fine in one java file. But its always returning null in other java file. What could be the possible cause of this? How to debug/fix this issue?

working fine in this class

```
@Repository("MyClassRepo")
public class MyClassRepoImpl implements MyClassRepo {
    .......
    @Autowired
    private APIPermissionCheck apiPermissionCheck;
    .......
}
```

Not working in this class

```
public class ApiConnection {
    .......
    @Autowired
    private APIPermissionCheck apiPermissionCheck;
    .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your second class marked as spring bean? 
Do you scan the package in which your second class by spring?

you can view configuration sample at [spring site](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html)

**EDIT :**
Create a setter for the bean you're trying to inject

```
public void setApiPermissionCheck(APIPermissionCheck apiPermissionCheck){
       this.apiPermissionCheck = apiPermissionCheck 
}
```

Comment: you can put inside your spring config file (where you define beans) node like <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.sample/> btw don't forget to create a setter for your injecting APIPermissionCheck apiPermissionCheck; and try use the @Component

Comment: Yes setter created, still not helpful

Answer (score 0):

The class `ApiConnection` is not found by spring because it is neither annotated as `@Component` neither as `@Repository`.

If you annotate your class with `@Component` it should work.

Also ensure that the package with the class is scanned by spring.

Comment: My Web application is already configured so if its marked with @Component its autowired automatically, not sure why its not working for ApiConnection class.

Comment: what would be inside Repository brackets? I am not implementing it from any base class.

Comment: @coure2011 Please check that the package which contains the class `ApiConnection` is scanned by spring.

Comment: Yes Package scan is already happening on com.myweb.freshCode, and APIConnection class is inside com.myweb.freshCode package

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an interface to ApiConnection to verify it's being loaded by Spring Container.

```
ApiConneection implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        logger.info("Initializing context is:" + applicationContext);
    }

    ....
}
```

do the same for the Autowiring classes and verify they are being loaded withint the same context.

You problem is probably:

1. The bean is not initialized with a spring
2. Autowired beans belongs to another context
3. Context for ApiConnection is not instructed with <context:annotation-config/>

Comment: How to investigate/fix 2) Autowired beans belongs to another context?

Comment: Add the same interfaces to autowiring beans. Log the application context in the same way (there will be something like BlaBlaBla@12ax5121). Compare the adresses in Hex (after the @), they should be equal

Comment: Yes its setting correctly, I am getting logger.info Initializing context is:root for both ApiConnection and APIPermissionCheck class.

Comment: Try to output applicationContext.hashCode() along with the names. Root - says nothing, you might have multiple contexts.

Comment: ConfigurationManager@40b00a66 is generated after APIPermissionCheck, but no such value after ApiConnection

Comment: Try adding ApiConnection to the beans.xml manually, like <bean class="package.ApiConnection"/>;

Also verify you are importing Autowired annotation from Spring and your configuration file contains <context:annotation-config/>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As ApiConnection object is being created a lot of places manually so spring framework is not autowiring it.

Comment: So, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved it by adding a `@Service` to the second class `public class ApiConnection`. The first class already has a `@Service`. In this step, it still does not work (return `NullPointerException`). In addition, in the Class that use `ApiConnection`, let's say `ApplicationImpl`, I add @Autowired on `ApiConnection apiConnection;` (`ApiConnection apiConnection = new XXX` was used before). Then it works.